# can I bypass passing self object to a python class method?

Tags: python, self, google-classroom, python-class

I am working with google classroom api and one of the params of a function takes a callback.

```py
def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print 'Error adding user "{0}" to the course course: {1}'.format(
            request_id, exception)
    else:
        print 'User "{0}" added as a student to the course.'.format(
            response.get('profile').get('name').get('fullName'))
```

In my case the method is inside a class and as I know  every python method should take a self object but in this case this function will have specific params and I am not sure how to pass the self object or should I ignore self? the issue is I plan to use self inside of the function.
Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly pass `self`. But since `callback` doesn't have `self` as its first argument, are you sure it isn't annotated with `@staticmethod`?

Comment: What method are you talking about? You can pass *bound* methods as an argument (`somefunc(some_obj.method)`) or you can wrap a method call in a function (`somefunc(lambda *args: some_obj.method(*args))`), depending on your needs.

Comment: i was trying to understand ```@static and @class``` method for this exact reason. To be fair I am not sure if really need to use those decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I understand your dilema. Go ahead and include `self` as the first argument, since it will be passed implicitly by Python every time `callback()` gets called. All the other positional arguments (`request_id`, `response` and `exception`) will not be affected by the inclusion of `self` in the definition of the method's argument. i.e:

```
def callback(self, request_id, response, exception):
    # ...
```

If you weren't going to use the `self` object inside the `callback` method (now a function), then you could use the `@staticmethod` decorator upon the function's definition, but if I'm following you straight, that's not the case here.

**Edit:** If you need to pass a specific parameter without compromising the nature of the callback, you can use `partial`, from the `functools` module. I would do something as follows (In this example I'm using the parameter `request_id`, but it could be any other(s)):

```
from functools import partial

partial_callback = partial(callback, request_id='12345')
```

Now you can pass `partial_callback` instead of `callback` wherever you need that specific argument (`request_id` in my example) to be passed.

Please note: If you want to pass a parameter that was not defined in the original `callback` function, that will raise a `TypeError`. If that was the case, then redefine `callback`, using the special syntax `**kwargs`, so that `callback` now accept a keyworded, variable-length arguments, which will be stored as key-value pairs in a dictionary called `kwargs`.

Just note that in order to use the arguments inside the function definition, you must refer to them as `kwargs['whatever_argument_name']` (as you would do with any dictionary)

So, for example, if you want to pass an argument called `extraparam`, then you would need to have something as follows:

```
def callback(self, request_id, response, exception, **kwargs):
    # ...
    extraparam = kwargs.get('extraparam')
    if extraparam is not None:
        # ...

partial_callback = partial(callback, extraparam='whatever')
```

Comment: Thank you. You were right, it did work with out any issues. But Now i want to pass it a param. Callback is called like this batch.execute(callback=callback). Is there any way I can make it pass a param? My batch requests are executed in different threads. Is there a way that I can store something just for that thread?

Comment: Hey, bud! Maybe using `partial`? It seems like the perfect case use for that. You can import it from the `functools` module.

Comment: So like ```def callback (self, reqid,resp,excep, extrapaeam): pass test = partials(callback, req, resp ,except) ``` and from the batch it is  ```batch.append(bla, callback=test(extrapaeam)``` ? something like this? honestly can't wrap my head around it. is this accurate though? apologies for the mess. On a terribly broken phone.

Comment: Oh, no problem! Au contraire, I admire your tenacity given your situation. Let me update my answer to illustrate the use of `partial`. Hopefully that's what you need.